# How do I echo the first 500 lines of a file with php?

Tags: php

It's a pretty big file, it'll end up being around a gigabyte.

I just want to show the first 500 lines. The file is preformatted, as it is a log.

Comment: Initialise count; Open the file; Loop over it a line at  time, incrementing the count; Terminate when count reaches 500

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Have you looked at any of the threads on it; or tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the entire file to an array can exhaust the machine's memory.

It is better to read the file line-by-line as needed:

```
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
        if (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // Do whatever processing is needed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Do whatever processing is needed" ?

Comment: I mean display the row, transform it, etc.  Basically, do whatever you want with it.  This is a very memory efficient implementation.  It can handle files of any size, including those smaller than 500 lines.

Comment: Sorry if I sound noobish, but how do I just simply echo it?

Comment: You can use `print $line;` inside the loop

Comment: This works well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like;

```
<?php
$data = file('data.txt');
for($i=0;$i<500;$i++){
    echo $data[$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: Could easily blow available memory if it's a "pretty big file"